# What are these birds eye view stock photos called and where can I find them?

Tags: style-identification, stock-images

What are these birds eye view stock photos called and where can I find them?

[image]

I am trying to find pictures of the birds eye view images above, such as the book, stapler, pencil, and hand.

Comment: The picture of the stapler is not bird's eye, it's sideways.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the words '**from above**' after the item that you are looking for seems to do the trick in Getty, Shutterstock, Google Images, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try searching 'flat lays' in shutter stock or other stock site, that seems to be the modern term for these images.